Identical equation outputs a negative when it's supposed to be positive
I created 2 different programs for my intro to C++ class. One program has only one function and the other program has multiple functions that are getting called into the main function. I used the identical equation in both programs, but for some reason in the program with multiple functions the value is negative instead of positive.
I looked over the equation and where it's getting called, but I couldn't find anything that would've clearly changed the output to a negative when it's supposed to be positive.
Thanks for the help. I got rid of the c and cols variable in both of my for loops for my arrays. I replaced these variable with the subscript values I wanted and my output for my equation came out positive like it was supposed to.
Code with multiple functions
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std; 

const int CINDEX=3;
const int RINDEX=3;
void getArray(float [][CINDEX]);
void outArray(const float [][CINDEX]);
float dtmntArray(const float[][CINDEX]);

int main()
{
    cout<<"Calculation of 3 x 3 Determinant\n\n";
    char yn;
    do{
    float fArray[RINDEX][CINDEX];
    getArray(fArray);       //get array input
    outArray(fArray);       //output array
    float d=dtmntArray(fArray);                     //get determinant
    cout<<"The determinant of the above matrix is "<<d<<endl;
    cout<<"\nWould you like to Do another Matrix (Y/N)? "; //loop
    cin>>yn;
    }while (yn!='N');
}

void getArray(float iArray[][CINDEX])
{
    int r, c;
    for (r=1;r<=RINDEX;r++) {
    c=0;
    cout<<"What is Row "<<r<<" of the matrix? ";
    cin>>iArray[r-1][c]>>iArray[r-1][c++]>>iArray[r-1][c++];
    }
    
    return;
}

void outArray (const float oArray[][CINDEX])
{
    cout<<"3 x 3 Matrix entered is\n";
    int rows, cols;
    for (rows=0;rows<RINDEX;rows++) {
        cols=0;
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3)<<left<<setw(7)<<
        oArray[rows][cols]<<setw(7)<<oArray[rows][cols++]<<
        setw(7)<<oArray[rows][cols++]<<endl;
    }
    
    return;
}

float dtmntArray (const float dArray [][CINDEX])
{
    float determ;
    determ=(dArray[0][0]*dArray[1][1]*dArray[2][2])+
    (dArray[0][1]*dArray[1][2]*dArray[2][0])+
    (dArray[0][2]*dArray[1][0]*dArray[2][1])-
    (dArray[0][1]*dArray[1][0]*dArray[2][2])-
    (dArray[0][0]*dArray[1][2]*dArray[2][1])-
    (dArray[0][2]*dArray[1][1]*dArray[2][0]);
    
    return determ;
}

code with one function
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char yn;
    do{
        //create array
        const int RINDEX=3;
        const int CINDEX=3;
        float mArray [RINDEX] [CINDEX];
        //entering values for matrix
        cout<<"Calculation of 3 x 3 Determinant\n\n";
        cout<<"What is Row 1 of the matrix? ";
        cin>>mArray[0][0]>>mArray[0][1]>>mArray[0][2];
        cout<<"What is Row 2 of the matrix? ";
        cin>>mArray[1][0]>>mArray[1][1]>>mArray[1][2];
        cout<<"What is Row 3 of the matrix? ";
        cin>>mArray[2][0]>>mArray[2][1]>>mArray[2][2];
        //output Matrix
        cout<<"\n\n3 x 3 Matrix entered is\n";
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3)<<left<<setw(7)<<mArray[0][0]<<
            setw(7)<<mArray[0][1]<<setw(7)<<mArray[0][2]<<endl;
        cout<<setw(7)<<mArray[1][0]<<setw(7)<<mArray[1][1]<<
            setw(7)<<mArray[1][2]<<endl;
        cout<<setw(7)<<mArray[2][0]<<setw(7)<<mArray[2][1]<<
            setw(7)<<mArray[2][2]<<endl;
        //determinant
        float determ;
        determ=(mArray[0][0]*mArray[1][1]*mArray[2][2])+
        (mArray[0][1]*mArray[1][2]*mArray[2][0])+
        (mArray[0][2]*mArray[1][0]*mArray[2][1])-
        (mArray[0][1]*mArray[1][0]*mArray[2][2])-
        (mArray[0][0]*mArray[1][2]*mArray[2][1])-
        (mArray[0][2]*mArray[1][1]*mArray[2][0]);
        cout<<"The determinant of the above matrix is "<<determ<<endl;
        //Loop it
        cout<<"\nWould you like to Do another Matrix (Y/N)? ";
        cin>>yn;
    } while (yn!='N');
}


We can't guess your input. It's supposed that you assign input values to variables bypassing cin.

Please stop using "C" style arrays like this. Embed your data in a matrix class and pass that arround.  E.g. class Matrix  this is C++ after all (and using "C" style arrays with [] is just asking for problems)

C++ should look something like this : https://onlinegdb.com/E6M0uK2Xq (and whoever is teaching you C++ :  CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C"

It's a style thing, but whitespaces aren't evil.

When compiling a program, especially while you're learning the language, it would be wise to use the flag to enable all warnings (-Wall) and pay close attention to any warnings that are reported. The version of your program with the many functions reports:
$ c++ -Wall -std=c++11 version-with-functions.cpp
version-with-functions.cpp:32:39: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'c' [-Wunsequenced]
   32 |     cin>>iArray[r-1][c]>>iArray[r-1][c++]>>iArray[r-1][c++];
      |                      ~                ^
version-with-functions.cpp:45:55: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'cols' [-Wunsequenced]
   45 |         oArray[rows][cols]<<setw(7)<<oArray[rows][cols++]<<
      |                      ~~~~                             ^
2 warnings generated.

Now, this warning (which occurs twice) says that you're modifying a variable and using its value in the same expression, which does not guarantee execution order. Let's make this clear with a simpler example:
int a[] = {10, 20};
int i = 0;
cout << a[i++] + a[i] << endl;

By assuming that the order of evaluation is always left-to-right, one might think the above snippet of code will print 30. However, C++ does not guarantee left-to-right evaluation in the operands of most operators, including +. It is not necessary that the value of i in the second operand a[i] will be 1, because of the i++ in the first operand. In general, you should avoid expressions that arbitrarily modify and use the same variable. You can read more on the order of evaluation in C++.
Let's now fix this. In both of these lines, you want to do something with successive elements of a row. E.g., in line 32, what you really want to do is:
cin >> iArray[r-1][c] >> iArray[r-1][c+1] >> iArray[r-1][c+2];

(In fact, you don't even need c here, as its value is always zero.)
Notice that the postfix increment operator c++ returns the value of c before incrementing, so this line would not be equivalent to what you had, even if evaluation order was guaranteed to be left-to-right.
If you wanted to increment c (there's no point in doing it in your program), you could increment it once in after this line:
cin >> iArray[r-1][c] >> iArray[r-1][c+1] >> iArray[r-1][c+2];
c += 2

Or, you could keep the operator for incrementing (the prefix version, that returns the value after incrementing) but split this in more expressions:
cin >> iArray[r-1][c];
cin >> iArray[r-1][++c];
cin >> iArray[r-1][++c];

Or, if you prefer the postfix operator for some reason:
cin >> iArray[r-1][c++];
cin >> iArray[r-1][c++];
cin >> iArray[r-1][c];

There may be more flaws in your program, but I'd start by fixing these ones.
